# JMS Serializer Bundle: Deserialize XML to Nested Objects

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I need to deserialize the following XML into an object graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <result>
        <success>true</success>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>foo</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>bar</name>
        </item>
    </result>
    <metadata>
        <key1>value1</key1>
        <key2>value2</key2>
    </metadata>
</response>
```

There should be 3 linked classes:

```
class Response
{
    /**
     * @var Result
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("AcmeBundle\Model\Result")
     */
    protected $result;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("array<string, string>")
     */
    protected $metadata;
}
```

,

```
class Result
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("success")
     * @Serializer\Type("boolean")
     */
    protected $success;

    /**
     * @var Item[]
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("item")
     * @Serializer\Type("array<AcmeBundle\Model\Item>")
     */
    protected $items = array();
}
```

,

```
class Item
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("id")
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("name")
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

When I try to deserialize it, I get the following result:

```
var_dump($serializer->deserialize($xml, Response::class, 'xml'));
```

:

```
object(AcmeBundle\Model\Response)#918 (2) {
  ["result":protected]=>
  object(AcmeBundle\Model\Result)#933 (2) {
    ["success":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["items":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["metadata":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

So there are 2 issues:

1. It doesn't deserialize the inline XML list (items)
2. It doesn't deserialize the "metadata" items

Any ideas how to make it work without manual deserialization in a handler? If it doesn't seem to be possible using only proper annotations, any ideas how to properly do that in a custom handler would be much appreciated.
BTW, the serialization from the objects to XML works fine and generates the proper structure.

Symfony 3.2.4, JMSSerializerBundle 1.1, the cache is clear, the original XML format cannot be modified.

Comment: Use @MaxDepth() annotation.

Comment: @MathieuDormeval, it doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: Have a look to https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/issues/522

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.
Does the real xml have a namespace?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response xmlns="http://example.com/response">
    <result>
        <success>true</success>
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>foo</name>
        </item>
        <item>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>bar</name>
        </item>
    </result>
    <metadata>
        <key1>value1</key1>
        <key2>value2</key2>
    </metadata>
</response>
```

If so you need to define the namespace as Class metadata

```
/**
 * @Serializer\XmlNamespace(uri="http://example.com/response")
 */
class Result
{
[...]
}
```

For arrays the serializer uses xpath, which needs a valid namespace.

After this change all my arrays deserialized as they should.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same pb, I used your exemple as a POC

Here is what I made to make it works. I hope it will helps somebody

```
class Response
{
    /**
     * @var Result
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("App\Serialiser\Result")
     */
    protected $result;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("array<string, string>")
     * @Serializer\XmlKeyValuePairs
     */
    protected $metadata;
}
```

,

```
class Item
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("id")
     * @Serializer\Type("integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("name")
     * @Serializer\Type("string")
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

,

```
class Result
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("success")
     * @Serializer\Type("boolean")
     */
    protected $success;

    /**
     * @var Item[]
     *
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("item")
     * @Serializer\Type("array<App\Serialiser\Item>")
     * @Serializer\XmlList(inline=true, entry="item")
     */
    protected $items = array();
}
```

result

```
object(App\Serialiser\Response)#1381 (2) {
  ["result":protected]=>
  object(App\Serialiser\Result)#1399 (2) {
    ["success":protected]=>
    bool(true)
    ["items":protected]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(App\Serialiser\Item)#1407 (2) {
        ["id":protected]=>
        int(1)
        ["name":protected]=>
        string(3) "foo"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(App\Serialiser\Item)#1406 (2) {
        ["id":protected]=>
        int(2)
        ["name":protected]=>
        string(3) "bar"
      }
    }
  }
  ["metadata":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key1"]=>
    string(6) "value1"
    ["key2"]=>
    string(6) "value2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not leave giant blocks of code like this. Leave the minimum amount of code necessary to answer the question.